# How do I get an SVG map to redraw on window resize?

Tags: javascript, svg, dictionary

Currently the map will redraw when the window is resized but the height of the containing div seems unaffected.  This causes the map to be unable to be redrawn larger and if it is redrawn smaller it has way too much spacing above and below it.

Here is the code. 
http://codepen.io/chrisgosling/pen/jLefu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a wrapper element...

```
<div id="container">
  <div id='visualization'></div>
  <div id="message"></div>
</div>
```

Then add the following CSS:

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#visualization {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LfCcl

Comment: This is the way I would do it. :)

Comment: Works perfectly.  I knew it would be something simple.  Thanks so much!